# $y'''+p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$ such that $p,q,r$ are continues functions in $[a,b]$. $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ are different solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'''+p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$ such that $p,q,r$ are continues functions in $[a,b]$.

$y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ are different solutions that have common tangent point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0\in [a,b].$

$1.$ Find the maximal number of linearly independent solutions? $(y_i , i\in [4])$

$2.$ Is it possible that each pair of solutions $((y_i,y_j) , i\neq j\in [4])$ are linear dependent ?

**My try:**

First of all, I don't get how it is possible that two solutions have a common point $(x_0,y_0)$ since by getting an initial condition there are two possible solutions.

$1.$I think the correct answer is $3$ since the o.d.e is third-order o.d.e.

$2.$ I think it is possible if $y_0=0$.

Lets take $y_1,y_2=c_1y_1,y_3=c_2y_1,y_4=c_3y_1.$

All these solutions are tangent in $(x_0,0)$ and linear dependant.

Thanks!

Comment: Does "common tangent point" also mean that the derivative at that point is equal? And in 2), should the question not be if the pairs could all be linearly **in**dependent?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don’t know if derivative is equal , and in 2) is dependent , thanks!

Comment: Mathematics is a precise science. Words have very specific meanings. If in geometry or a curve description it is said that curves are tangent, then they share the same tangent line. In this case here it means that the derivative is the same, so to be different, the second derivatives in $x_0$ have to be different. Now check linear dependence via the Wronski determinant...