# Maximal number of solutions to an ODE that are linearly independent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y'''+a_1(x)y''+a_2(x)y'+a_3(x)y=0$ where $a_i$ are all continuous functions in $[a,b]$. Let $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ be four different solutions to the equations, that are all tangent to each other at $a<x_0<b$. What is the maximal number of solutions (among $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$) that are linearly independent in $[a,b]$?

First, since the solutions to a linear, homogeneous ODE of order 3 form a 3-dimensional vector space, we in general must have that at most 3 of these functions are linearly independent.
Second, if I understand this correctly, we have that $\forall i=1,2,3,4: \, y_i(x_0)=m, y_i'(x_0)=n$ for some $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$. The Wronskian of a pair of functions is therefore equal to $0$, but does this imply every pair is linearly dependent? I am not sure. In addition, there is a second part to this question, and I am not sure how is this different from the first part if this is the answer -

> Is it possible that every pair out of the functions $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ are linearly dependent?

Will be happy if someone will be able to help me figure out how to build an example to the second part, and understand how to correctly answer the first one.

Thank you!

Comment: This question was recently asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336129, you have already more insight than asked there. But the same question remains to the second question, should the pairs not be "independent"? If two solutions are tangent and linearly dependent, they have already to be identical.  /// The Wronskian of a third-order DE is for 3 solutions and is the determinant of the matrix where the columns contain function value, first and second derivative.

Comment: Thanks you @LutzLehmann . So, if I understand this correctly, the answer is indeed 3 to the first question? 
What about the second one? How can I construct a family such that each pair is linearly dependent? 
Thank you!

Comment: No, the Wronskian matrix for 3 of these functions at $x_0$ would have 2 rows of identical entries, which gives determinant zero. As for the second, as the functions have to be different, they have different second derivative at $x_0$. They can only be multiples of each other if the function value and first derivative are zero at $x_0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann : Got it . Thank you!